# homestead up fails - laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

I am trying to get homestead vm to work but i have some issues.

That is what happens when using homestead up command.

```
abdulaziz@abdulaziz-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510:~$ homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:492:in `initialize': Permission denied - /home/abdulaziz/.vagrant.d/data/lock.dotlock.lock (Errno::EACCES)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:492:in `open'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:492:in `block in lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:485:in `lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:491:in `lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:491:in `lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in `action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Notably that /home/abdulaziz/.vagrant.d/data/lock.dotlock.lock file does not even exist

any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i tried something maybe wrong but homestead is working now. i will see if this will break it in the future or not.

when i used homestead up command it kept giving me files that i did not have permission to use. the problem was that these files did not exist from first place. so what i did is i created all these files and give the right permission and the machine is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there was a tab error in the homestead.yaml file when I got an error like this. Copy the yaml file again and save then vagrant up --provision maybe fix this!

[LARAVEL ERRORS...Hashicorp/embedded error when vagrant up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63511431/laravel-errors-hashicorp-embedded-error-when-vagrant-up?noredirect=1#comment112307278_63511431)