# LARAVEL ERRORS - Hashicorp/embedded error after vagrant provision

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I installed Laravel/Homestead and vagrant. Both `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` commands have been successfully implemented but when I create a project and do `vagrant provision`, vagrant doesn't work again. Below is an example of the error received after `provision`.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GEsq.jpg)

I have reinstalled several times but always get the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189128/cant-start-vagrant-after-laravel-homestead-installation-vagrant-up Might be of some help

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've been working for about 1 week and I want to share with you the solution that got me a result.
This parse error, which I noticed was due to a tab in the homestead.yaml file, was fixed when I copied the homestead.yaml file again.

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects_Laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects_Laravel

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects_Laravel/laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

this is my homestead.yaml
You can get the solution by copying it and editing your own file names. good luck.